# Add 2 HOC to a component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component in a react js app, that I want it to use router and translation.

```
interface CommonHeaderProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
}

class CommonHeader extends React.Component<CommonHeaderProps> {  

  render() {


    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({

})

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(CommonHeader));
```

I would like this component to have be

`withRouter()(Component)`
and 
`withTransaltion()(Component)`

but doing this do not work

```
export default withTranslation()(withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(CommonHeader)));
```

Comment: where is `withTranslation` come from ?

Comment: it s an import from i18react
https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as this

```
const Component = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps(CommonHeader));
export default withTransaltion()(Component)
```

Or you can use compose from Redux as

```
import { compose } from 'redux'

const Component = 
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps(CommonHeader));
export default compose(
 withTransaltion,
 withRouter,
 )(Component)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this, but I have a problem when I call the component `JSX element type 'CommonHeader' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: I think that's related to typescript

Comment: I get this error though: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__reactAutoBindPairs')`